# Can haskell-src-meta be installed to be used with GHC 7.10.1?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I tried, but I got this error:

https://gist.github.com/Wizek/a3e02b93b9f672a91f54

I remember trying with GHC 7.8.4 too, and AFAIR that also failed similarly.

## Misc

I've used a new & empty cabal sandbox

cabal-install version 1.22.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your happy executable needs to be upgraded. You can install the new version with cabal-install. Alternatively, using stack will automatically install the correct version of happy.

Comment: Indeed, putting happy-1.19.5 into my path (was 1.18.9) allowed me to install haskell-src-meta. Thanks!